# how to get table header name in handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a handsontable like below

```
var $container = $("#example1");
$container.handsontable({
data: data1,
rowHeaders:true,
colHeaders: ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thr","Fri","Sat"],
cols:13,
minSpareRows: 100
});
<div id="example1" class="dataTable" style="width: 1170px; height: 450px; 
overflow:scroll;"></div>
```

i can access table tr values

```
 var rowList = $("#example1").handsontable("getData");
 rowList = $.grep(rowList,function(array,index)
 {
  // here i can access values from first row  


 });
```

I need to access headers "Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thrs","Fri","Sat"
How to do this...? ple help ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited this:

```
 var rowHeaderList = $("#example1").handsontable("getRowHeader"); //for row headers 
 var colHeaderList = $("#example1").handsontable("getColHeader"); //for column headers
```

Comment: its returning empty array, not contain any values...anyway thank u.

Comment: my bad, you have column headers, not row, try this one: 
`var colHeaderList = $("#example1").handsontable("getColHeader");`

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
hotInstance.getColHeader()
```

Source: https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/5.0.2/Core.html#getColHeader